# duplicate a column in keras tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am writing a custom loss function for semi supervised learning on cifar-10 dataset, for which I need to duplicate columns of my tensor for creating a sort of mask which I then multiply with the activation values to later sum over.

My loss function is a sum of entropy and cross entropy for unlabelled and labeled samples. I add an extra class and set it to 1 for unlabelled samples.

I then create a mask for identifying row indices of unlabelled samples from the `y_true` tensor. From that I should get a (n_samples, 1) tensor which I need to repeat/duplicate/copy to a (n_samples, 11) tensor that I can multiply with the activation values in `y_pred`

Loss function code:

```
        a = np.ones((mini_batch_size, 1)) * 10
        a_var = K.variable(value=a)
        v = K.cast(K.equal(K.cast(K.argmax(y_true, axis=1), 'float32'), a_var), 'float32')
        e_loss = K.sum(K.concatenate([v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v], axis=-1) * K.log(y_pred) * y_pred)
        m_u = K.sum(K.cast(K.equal(K.cast(K.argmax(y_true, axis=1), 'float32'), a_var), 'float32'))

        b = np.ones((mini_batch_size, 1)) * 10
        b_var = K.variable(value=b)
        v2 = K.cast(K.not_equal(K.cast(K.argmax(y_true, axis=1), 'float32'), b_var), 'float32')
        ce_loss = K.sum(K.concatenate([v2, v2, v2, v2, v2, v2, v2, v2, v2, v2, v2], axis=1) * K.log(y_pred))
        m_l = K.variable(value=float(mini_batch_size), dtype='float32') #- m_u

        return -((e_loss/m_u) + (ce_loss/m_l))
```

The error I get is:

```
InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: Incompatible shapes: [40,11] vs. [40,440]
     [[{{node loss_36/dense_74_loss/mul_2}}]]
     [[metrics_28/acc/Mean/_2627]]
  (1) Invalid argument: Incompatible shapes: [40,11] vs. [40,440]
     [[{{node loss_36/dense_74_loss/mul_2}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

My batch size is 40.
I need my concatenated tensor to be of size [40, 11] not [40, 440]

Answer (score 1):

I don't have real data to test whether the loss properly works, but this got rid of that `InvalidArgumentError` and did work with `model.fit()` for a dense model.

Few changes I did,

- You don't have to repeat your `v` 11 times to multiply that with `y_pred`. All you need is reshape it to (-1,1) - (Will save you memory)
- Got rid of all the `K.variables`. Now this is something I want to check with you, you are not trying to optimize `a_var` and `b_var` right (i.e. that's not a part of the model)? (Apparently, that's what's causing the issue. I need to dive deeper to see why). It seems the whole point of `a_var` and `b_var` is to perform boolean logics `equal` and `not_equal`, which works just fine with the constant.
- Made `m_l` a `K.constant`

```
def loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):

    v = K.cast(K.equal(K.cast(K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1), 'float32'), 10), 'float32')
    e_loss = K.sum(K.reshape(v, (-1,1)) * K.log(y_pred) * y_pred)
    m_u = K.sum(K.cast(K.equal(K.cast(K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1), 'float32'), 10), 'float32'))

    v2 = K.cast(K.not_equal(K.cast(K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1), 'float32'), 10), 'float32')
    ce_loss = K.sum(K.reshape(v2, (-1,1)) * K.log(y_pred))
    m_l = K.constant(value=float(mini_batch_size), dtype='float32') #- m_u

    return -((e_loss/m_u) + (ce_loss/m_l))
```

**Note**: Depending on the batch size within the loss function is a bad idea. Try to get rid of any `batch_size` dependent operations (especially for shape of tensors). You can see that I only have kept `mini_batch_size` to set `m_l`. But I would suggest setting this to some constant instead of `min_batch_size`. Because, if a batch with `<40` comes through, you are using a different loss function for that batch. And your results aren't comparable between different batch sizes, as your loss function changes.